# Setting Page Title - headTitle() - Zend Framework 2 ZF2

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc

I am currently in the process of building an application with ZF2, everything is going well so far, but I am just having trouble with the page titles (as in the `<title>` tag in the `<head>`).

In my `layout.phtml` I have it statically set a string using `$this->headTitle()`.

I want it to basically include the name of the module, controller and action by default, just like the doc page suggests:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.head-title.html

However when I try and implement the example code, I get an Exception.
Frankly the documentation should at least show you the best place to put this code.

I am looking for an example that a ZF2 noob can follow. I basically want to place some code somewhere (presumably Application\Module.php) so that I can set the default title as "Module - Controller - Action", then I need an example of how to override it easily from each controller or view (whichever is preferred)... please help! :)

Comment: What's the exception. I'd bet money it's a class not found exception? As this example is missing the leading slash `\Zend\Controller\Front`

Comment: If I paste the example code directly into an action, with the leading slash I still get  Fatal: Class 'Zend\Controller\Front' not found.

Comment: That being said from the controller I can just do $request = $this->getRequest(); Although I dont believe the controller is where I should be setting the default title from?

Comment: OMG, i just noticed what manual you're using, better see http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.view.helpers.html#headtitle-helper They got way better examples :) You have to know that even in 2.1 the documentation currently is the biggest drawback for ZF2, though we're all working on it to fix things like this. On readthedocs you'll always find the latest one

Comment: @Sam You my friend are a star! readthedocs is defo the place to go for these things. Awesome mate! You have made my day! :)

Comment: @Sam I am fairly inexperienced with StackOverflow, I have just added an answer, is that correct, or should you have done it?? Then I accept it?

Comment: Fine like this ;) If your final solution were to differ from the one linked, then you should post your actual code, but it's ok for a simple quesiton just like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Sams comment...
Readthedocs has the working example: http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.view.helpers.html#headtitle-helper

Thanks for your help Sam!